# "Joining" different XML entities via keys with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to raise a warning to the user in their accounting system if certain criteria are met.

Below is a snippet of my XML, very clean, only showing relevant parts:

```
<DATA>
    <ACCOUNTING>
        <POSTINGS>
            <POSTING KEY="815" ID="PR0">
                    ...
                <EXPENSE_TYPE_ID NAME="Expense Type ABC">123456</EXPENSE_TYPE_ID> 
                <AMOUNT>40000</AMOUNT> 
                    ...
            </POSTING>
        </POSTINGS>
        <LINES>
            <LINE KEY="1450" POSTING="PR0">
                    ...
                <BOOKKEEPING_TYPE>D</BOOKKEEPING_TYPE> 
                <ACCOUNT_ID NAME="Debit Account Name HHHH">112233</ACCOUNT_ID> 
                <AMOUNT>40000</AMOUNT> 
                <DESCRIPTION>Expense Type ABC</DESCRIPTION> 
                <SPECIALS_TYPE_A>1</SPECIALS_TYPE_A> 
                    ...
            </LINE>
            <LINE KEY="1451" POSTING="PR0">
                    ...
                <BOOKKEEPING_TYPE>C</BOOKKEEPING_TYPE> 
                <ACCOUNT_ID NAME="Credit Account Name TTTT">987654</ACCOUNT_ID> 
                <AMOUNT>-40000</AMOUNT> 
                <DESCRIPTION>Expense Type ABC</DESCRIPTION> 
                <SPECIALS_TYPE_A>1</SPECIALS_TYPE_A> 
                    ...
            </LINE>
        </LINES>
    </ACCOUNTING>
</DATA>
```

The message must be shown based on the following criteria:

1. The individual posting line's amount must exceed 20,000
2. A special type must be initialized with the value '1'
3. The name of the account must not contain the words 'Tax Account'
4. The posting line must be of debit bookkeeping type
5. A list of selected expense types has been used with the posting line

Below is my current implementation, which works fine in "normal" cases:

```
<xsl:variable name="AmountWarningLower" select="20000" />
<xsl:for-each select="ACCCOUNTING/LINES/LINE[
    DESCRIPTION = 'Expense Type ABC' or 
    DESCRIPTION = 'Expense Type DEF' or 
        ...
    ]">
    <xsl:if test="(SPECIALS_TYPE_A = '1') and 
        (AMOUNT &gt; $AmountWarningLower) and 
        not(contains(ACCOUNT_ID/@NAME,'Tax Account')) 
        and not(BOOKKEEPING_TYPE='C')">

        //Print message
        //Print message

    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Currently I have solved requirement #5 by a long list of OR's to match the posting line's description.

This isn't ideal, as the customer has the option to change the expense type's description, which will break my solution.

But because the application does not include expense type id in the Line entity, I could not map those directly.

Vice versa the application does not include specials type information in the Posting entity.

I see there's a key match between the rows in "Posting Record ID", ie. "PR0".

"KEY" has no direct link between the two.

Is there a way how I can "join" the two XML entities, by matching the "Posting Record ID", ie. "PR0", and then update my solution to match expense type id from the Posting entity, instead of the line description from the Line entity?

Ideally something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ACCCOUNTING/LINES/LINE[
    @EXPENSE_TYPE_ID = '123456' or 
    @EXPENSE_TYPE_ID = '789123' or 
        ...
    ]">
```

Hope this makes sense, and is possible.

Thanks in advance for you afford in helping finding a solution.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You can use a [key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to lookup the value of "PRO" and get "815" in return - if that's what you want. You should know how to do this from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146629/summarizing-dynamic-multiple-project-costs-with-shares

Comment: Hi Michael, my XSLT friend ;-)

This time, I need to cross-reference between XML entities, as different parts of the information is listed in the different entities.

Let me explain with a SQL analogy.

Currently I can only sort out how to select and compare the values from the Line entity by:
SELECT ?
FROM line l
WHERE l.description in ('Expense Type ABC', 'Expense Type DEF' ...)

Instead I need to "join" the two XML entities in order to perform:
SELECT p.expensetype_id
FROM line l, posting p
WHERE l.posting = p.posting
AND p.expensetype_id in ('123456', '789123' ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to cross-reference between XML entities, as different parts of
>   the information is listed in the different entities.

That's what a key does: first, you define the looked-up entity and the key value:

```
<xsl:key name="postings-by-id" match="POSTING" use="ID" />
```

Now, any time you use this key with a value of "PRO", it will address the POSTING node that has the matching ID value - for example, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ACCCOUNTING/LINES/LINE">
    <xsl:variable name="posting-code" select="key('postings-by-id', @POSTING)/@KEY" />
    ...
```

### Edit:

Since you cannot use a variable before you have defined it, and a repeated reference to the key would be awkward, it might be more convenient in your case to reverse the direction in which the key operates.

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <categories>
        <category id="501" name="red"/>
        <category id="502" name="green"/>
        <category id="503" name="blue"/>
    </categories>
    <items>
        <item id="1" category="red"/>
        <item id="2" category="blue"/>
        <item id="3" category="green"/>
        <item id="4" category="blue"/>
        <item id="5" category="red"/>
        <item id="6" category="green"/>
        <item id="7" category="blue"/>
        <item id="8" category="red"/>
        <item id="8" category="green"/>
        <item id="9" category="blue"/>
    </items>
</root>
```

Here, we wish to select only items that are either in the "green" or the "blue" category - but to do so using the category `id` values "502" and "503".

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-category" match="item" use="@category" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('item-by-category', categories/category[@id ='502' or @id ='503']/@name)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <item id="2" category="blue"/>
   <item id="3" category="green"/>
   <item id="4" category="blue"/>
   <item id="6" category="green"/>
   <item id="7" category="blue"/>
   <item id="8" category="green"/>
   <item id="9" category="blue"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I've had a big project release and later been on holiday. Thank you very much Michael. Your answer once again pointed me in the right direction, and I was able to implement a solution that solved the exact requirement.